# Monthly repeated notifecations android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I Have an app that has a database with information about users or such each record has a subscription expiration date, day of the month, which they need to renew subscription so I need my app to trigger a notification  whenever a user's expiration date and I honestly can't figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give some more information. Though sounds like, your app may be running as a service in background and you can post trigger notification. You can use PostDelayedMessage. Just read for your next entry for notification and then post it..Also, catch the boot broadcasts from the  system, to reset it. You can keep next trigger ntf time in Sharedpreferences..so that you need not to read it everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Need more info. Probably based on your post, Try using alarmManger.

alarmManager.set(). "The alarm is an Intent broadcast that goes to a broadcast receiver".

Hope my answer solves your problem. Lot of examples are there online. have a look.

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))